# ABinitio- how to get/return first not null column from a list of columns

Tags: ab-initio

I am new to ABinitio, need help :
I have 6 columns with address fields , trying to find function in Abinitio which returns first not null value taking list of columns as arguments(something similar to Coalesce in Teradata or NVL in Oracle)

my requirement : should return first non null column value from this (col1,col2,col3,col4..)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. You've posted your requirements, but have forgotten to post a question. What would you like us to help you with? Note that SO is not a free code writing service, i.e. make sure to present a well-scoped and -researched problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's 3 month old, but in case somebody else looks for the same:

```
first_defined(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, default_value_if_you_need_it);
```